# Does this code find the norm of k column?

Tags: c, norm

Does this code work correctly in order to find the norm of K column?

```
double norm2x2(double A[5][7], int K)
{
    K=K-1;
    double max=fabs(A[0][K]);
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<5;i++)
        if(fabs(A[i][K])>max)
            max=fabs(A[i][K]);
    return max;
}
```

I wrote this algorithm as answer for the question:
Write a C program that gets as parameter a 5X7 array and  calculates the norm of the Kth column where K is also a parameter;

Comment: Well it finds a norm of that vector. Only you can tell whether it finds the norm you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Yes. More precisely it calculates the maximum norm of the `K`-th column, where `K` is the 1-based index of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code does find the `l_∞` norm of the `K`th column (with 1-based indexing, i.e. the leftmost column has the index of 1) of a matrix sized `5x7`.

Comment: Actually, that's the `l_∞` norm, `l_1` is the sum of absolute values.

Comment: @DanielFischer, yeah, felt something, edited. Well, actually, `l_k`s are in infinite-dimensional spaces, I believe, but my point was that this code works one special case